# jQuery: Use function instead of $(document).ready

Tags: jquery

I am using the Piety plugin on a website that displays leaderboard profiles.
Each profile contains a different amount of elements to which Piety is applied and I have found that `$(document).ready` is triggered before all these elements have loaded.

My solution so far has been to move Piety from `$(document).ready` to `$(window).load` - Which works great for most of the profiles.  However, the people at the top of the leaderboard have extremely large profiles, which creates quite a wait before `$(window).load` will kick in and work through all of the Piety elements.

I am wondering if there would be any performance issues if I was to call each pie individually as they are loaded, instead of waiting for `$(window).load` and letting jQuery do it all in one go.

Something like..

From:

```
$(window).load(function(){
   $("span.pie").peity("pie", { ... })
});
```

To:

```
function loadPie(id){
    $("#"+id).peity("pie", { ... })
}
```

..and then loadPie after each element.

Comment: This seems like a design issue.  On this board, some of the more seasoned members would have similar issues viewing their profile were it not for summaries and pagination.  Perhaps cutting down on the number of piety elements by putting a summarized section or pagination would resolve the performance issue observed by members with an enormous # of 'piety' elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the profiles are loaded asynchronously after DOM ready, then yes, initializing peity on each one after they are loaded makes sense. $(window).load() waits until **everything** else on the page (profile related or not) is completely loaded.

One thing to consider is the resources piety requires for each instance. Depending on how many profiles / pie charts you have, it may be faster to call them all at once after the *last* profile is loaded (but before window.load). I will try and update this with a jsperf in a bit... headed to work now :)

Comment: There's nothing special about the way the the document is loaded.  It is just a vertical stack of DIVs with 1 pie in each.  Most pages were fine, but the rare page that is really big would have `$(document).ready` called at some point before the column has finished, leaving the bottom portion of the column without Pies.  Your excellent answer has proved again that the simplest method is often the best.. And the one that I overlooked!  I have just switched out the `$(window).load` for a function and called that after the last DIV, and it is providing the exact functinality that I need.

Comment: And of course, it completely negates my question as it is using Piety in exactly the same way it did before.